# how to change button colour programmatically using material component for Android API below 23?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I am using material component. my normal button is like this

[image]

and I set it in style like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/StandardButtonStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="StandardButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

now I need to make my button look like the image below (but without icon in it) **programmatically** for my app up to API 21.

[image]

before using material icon, I can set it by using drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#474241"/> 
    <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and then set it programmatically like this

```
button.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.inactive_button)
```

but it doesn't work anymore, now I am confused.....

I have tried to make a style like this

```
<style name="InactiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:fillColor">@color/grey_light_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_dark_super</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

and then apply it programmatically like this

```
button.setTextAppearance(mContext,R.style.InactiveButtonStyle)
```

but it doesn't work. `setTextAppearance` method that using context as input argument is actually deprecated, and if I use `setTextAppearance` method without context is not suitable for API 21 (minimum API 23). I don't if this is the cause that it doesn't work

so how to change button colour programmatically using material component for Android API below 23 ?